# Clarification about Boost multi-index container

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost

I am trying to learn about Boost multi-index, may I please seek some help regarding that.

The data looks like as follows:

```
 index1, index2, index3, index4, value
 alpha   a       1       101     0.5
 alpha   a       1       102     0.6
 ...    ...     ...     ....     ...
 alpha   a       1       120     0.7
 alpha   a       2       101     0.3
 ...    ...     ...     ....     ... 
 alpha   a       2       101     0.3
 alpha   b       1       101     0.3
 ...    ...     ...     ....     ...
 beta   a       1       101     0.7
 ...    ...     ...     ....     ...
```

Now I have created a structure:

```
struct data
{
   data(std::string index1,
      std::string index2,
      int index3,
      int index4,
      double value):index1_(index1),index2_(index2),index3_(index3),
      index4_(index4),value_(value){}
    std::string index1_;
    std::string index2_;
    int index3_;
    int index4_;    
    double value_;
};
```

and also have:

```
struct index1{};
struct index2{};
struct index3{};
struct index4{};
struct value{}; // I guess i do not need this because this is a data point
                // and not an index. Can someone please comment ?
```

Next I created a typedef as follows: I am not sure whether to use "ordered_unique" or "ordered_non_unique". Can someone please help.

I have the confusion because the 4-tuple (index1,index2,index3,inde4) is unique co-ordinate pointing to a data value. But for each of them there are repeated occurrence (e.g. for index1 the string "alpha" is repeated several times)

```
typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
    data, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
           boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<index1>,boost::multi_index::member<data, std::string,&data::index1_> >,
           boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<index2>,boost::multi_index::member<data, std::string,&data::index2_> >,
           boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<index3>,boost::multi_index::member<data, int,&data::index3_> >,
           boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<index4>,boost::multi_index::member<data, int,&data::index4_> >,

     // not sure if I need the line below. because it is not an index

           boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<value>,boost::multi_index::member<data, double,&data::value_> >,
       >
    > data_map;
```

Next in the main() I populate the data by looping through each data point and doing an insert like I give below:

```
 data_map DATA;
 DATA.insert(data(alpha,a,1,101,0.5));
```

Thereafter, I want to check what is the range of say index4 (i.e. what is the minimum and maximum value). I am trying something like:

```
    const boost::multi_index::index<data_map,index4>::type& in_index4 = boost::multi_index::get<index4>(DATA);
    int nIndex4 = in_index4.size(); // I do not get the correct size here
```

Also when I try I do not get the intended results.

```
    boost::multi_index::index<data_map,index4>::type::const_iterator index_itr=in_index4.begin();
    for(;index_itr!=in_index4.end();index_itr++)
    {
        int xx = (*index_itr).index4_;
    }
```

Can someone please point out my mistakes and help me with my understanding. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you really trying to do something related to geometry? (Boost Geometry indexing is likely a better idea). Or is it image data (consider Boost GIL). In any case, consider making `(index1,index2,index3,index4)` a type.

Comment: thanks again. your answer cleared up my confusions. I will check out boost geometry. I am not doing any image processing or something related to geometry (but maybe it can be mapped. not sure though, i have to think through it). i am trying to process big data with lot of "tags" (which are the indexes in this case). something similar to what "Essbase" cubes does.

Comment: that's called OLAP. I'd consider optimized storage (likely in a memory mapped segment) for this, or a proper ROLAP view of existing relational data (use existing tools!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q.**:
>
> ```
> struct value{}; // I guess i do not need this because this is a data point
>                 // and not an index. Can someone please comment ?
> ```

Only create the indexes you use.

> **Q.**: *I am not sure whether to use `ordered_unique` or `ordered_non_unique`. Can someone please help.*
>
> *I have the confusion because the 4-tuple (index1,index2,index3,inde4) is unique co-ordinate pointing to a data value. But for each of them there are repeated occurrence (e.g. for index1 the string "alpha" is repeated several times)*

You need a unique index on the composite key:

```
bmi::indexed_by<
    bmi::ordered_unique<
        bmi::composite_key<data,
            bmi::member<data, std::string, &data::index1_>,
            bmi::member<data, std::string, &data::index2_>,
            bmi::member<data, int,         &data::index3_>,
            bmi::member<data, int,         &data::index4_>
        >
    >
>
```

> **Q.**: *Next in the main() I populate the data by looping through each data point and doing an insert like I give below:*

May I suggest uniform initialization:

```
Table table {
    //index1, index2, index3, index4, value
    data {   "alpha", "a", 1, 101, 0.5 },
    data {   "alpha", "a", 1, 102, 0.6 },
    // ...
    data {   "alpha", "a", 1, 120, 0.7 },
    data {   "alpha", "a", 2, 101, 0.3 },
    // ...
    data {   "alpha", "a", 2, 101, 0.3 },
    data {   "alpha", "b", 1, 101, 0.3 },
    // ...
    data {   "beta",  "a", 1, 101, 0.7 },
};
```

> **Q.**: *Thereafter, I want to check what is the range of say index4 (i.e. what is the minimum and maximum value). I am trying something like:*
>
> ```
>   const boost::multi_index::index<data_map,index4>::type& in_index4 = boost::multi_index::get<index4>(DATA);
>   int nIndex4 = in_index4.size(); // I do not get the correct size here
> ```

`size()` returns the number of elements in the container, anyways. You can add the index

```
bmi::ordered_non_unique<
    bmi::tag<struct index4>, bmi::member<data, int, &data::index4_>
>
```

and "exploit" the fact that it is ordered:

```
int min4 = table.get<index4>().begin() ->index4_;
int max4 = table.get<index4>().rbegin()->index4_;
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2486b830003c34ad)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct data
{
    std::string index1_;
    std::string index2_;
    int         index3_;
    int         index4_;
    double      value_;
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

using Table = bmi::multi_index_container<
    data, bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::composite_key<data,
                bmi::member<data, std::string, &data::index1_>,
                bmi::member<data, std::string, &data::index2_>,
                bmi::member<data, int,         &data::index3_>,
                bmi::member<data, int,         &data::index4_>
            >
        >,
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct index4>,
            bmi::member<data, int, &data::index4_>
        >
    >
>;

int main() {
    Table table {
        //index1, index2, index3, index4, value
        data {   "alpha", "a", 1, 101, 0.5 },
        data {   "alpha", "a", 1, 102, 0.6 },
        // ...
        data {   "alpha", "a", 1, 120, 0.7 },
        data {   "alpha", "a", 2, 101, 0.3 },
        // ...
        data {   "alpha", "a", 2, 101, 0.3 },
        data {   "alpha", "b", 1, 101, 0.3 },
        // ...
        data {   "beta",  "a", 1, 101, 0.7 },
    };

    // max min index4, exploiting the ordered-ness of the index
    if (!table.empty()) {
        int min4 = table.get<index4>().begin() ->index4_;
        int max4 = table.get<index4>().rbegin()->index4_;

        std::cout << "index4: " << min4 << " - " << max4 << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
index4: 101 - 120
```

Comment: thank you very much. i get a better understanding from your answer.

Comment: thank you very much. one more question if i may. once the Table is constructed how do i get the value for the cor-ordinate { "alpha", "a", 1, 101 } i.e i want to "find" {"alpha", "a", 1, 101} the "value" and say update it.

Comment: Iterators are de-referenced like pointers. Just `it = table.find(..);` and then `*it` is your object (unless it wasn't found!)

Comment: should i try to find the object or the tuple ? what i am trying is boost::tuple<std::string, std::string, Size, Size, Size> index = boost::make_tuple("alpha", "a", 1, 101); and then i am trying to data  d= *(table.find(index)). but it is not working. i guess i am confused, but unable to catch the mistake.

Comment: You search an index by the index key; The key was defined as the composite (see the tuple). What you get is just the container element type.

Comment: i am just bummed. cannot figure out what the error is. i use: boost::tuple<std::string, std::string, Size, Size> index = boost::make_tuple("alpha", "a", 1, 101); i try to find using: auto data_it= table.find(index); but i cannot find the element.data_it is becoming equal to table. end(). the element is not found even though i know it is there. any idea what may be going on. i tried several ways in the last couple of hours.

Comment: Not without a SSCCE. It looks reasonable. You know it's there. How? Did you make any other indices unique?  Did you check ask insertions?